# Children's/ Teen novel: Boy protagonist sent through a maze on futuristic space station that keeps getting harder. Read in 1980s

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

[I posted this on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/21331539-children-s-teen-sci-fi-boy-protagonist-sent-through-a-maze-on-futurist), but thought it might be good to get ideas from a more specialised group.

Age group: children / teens

Date: 1970s / 80s (read it mid to late 80s).

Origin: British or American - no clear feeling on this.

Plot details (so far as I can remember):
Boy is in a futuristic space station. A trip through a maze is possibly an initiation to adulthood, but can also be a punishment. Boy is eventually sent on trip through maze. During the trip, he becomes aware the maze is changing - doors open and shut - and it gets progressively harder. The only hard detail I can recall is that he comes across two drinking fountains to keep him going. The first one gives him a drink, but the second gives him a powerful electric shock.

I've looked through some books, but it is not House of Stairs,
Tunnel in the Sky,
The Maze in the Heart of the Castle,
Ender's Game, The Man in the Maze, Space Station Ice-3,
Beyond the Labyrinth, Galax-Arena, But We Are Not of Earth,
Turlough and the Earthlink Dilemma,
Skymaze, The Maze, Star Voyager Academy, Space Demons,
The Learning Maze and Other Science Fiction, Cold Chills, The Cage
or Shinkei.

Comment: Also probably not _[A Maze of Death](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Maze_of_Death)_ although you never know with Philip K. Dick.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for taking the [tour], let us know if you need help with any other parts of the site, otherwise have a look at the [help] and also [asking]. You have plenty of details but should you feel the need [tag:story-identification] should link you to more things that could be added with an [edit].